# Product is in stock but can't be added to cart

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have a product (specifically a related product from a configurable) that by all apparent measures should be available, but when trying to add it to cart (selecting "medium" size from dropdown on configurable product page), I get

> This product is currently out of stock.
>
> Some of the products are currently out of stock

Things I've checked for the medium simple product:

> Manage Stock: Yes
>
> Qty: 3
>
> Stock Availability: In Stock
>
> Status: Enabled
>
> Visibility: Not Visible Individually

And all of these values match the `cataloginventory_stock_*` values.

I've reindexed and cleared cache.

1. Why can't I add this item to my cart?
2. Why is it showing up in the drop down if it's not salable?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there were two `medium` products associated with the configurable.  One was available, the other was not.  So the drop down showed the available one, but when trying to add to cart, used the disabled one.

I removed the disabled product from the associated products and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if any of those attributes is overridden in a specific store view.  (Meaning drop down "Choose Store View:" in the top left corner)